# Displayalert and userdialoges not showing in UI (Viewmodel)

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my viewmdodel class, I am calling a function from constructor. Inside of that function I am using Userdialoges and displayalert properties. But both are not showing in UI. Getting exception for both.

Displayalert Exception :

> Exception:>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

UserDialogs Exception :

> Exception:>System.ArgumentException: In android, you must call
>   UserDialogs.Init(Activity) from your first activity OR
>   UserDialogs.Init(App) from your custom application OR provide a
>   factory function to get the current top activity via
>   UserDialogs.Init(() => supply top activity)

I have also implemented the pull down to refresh option. When pull down I am calling the same function, but that call is not from the constructor. So when pull down UserDialoges and Displayalert are working.

My code:

```
  UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading"); 
  await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Internet Connection", "Ok");
```

So how can I activate the userdialoges and displayalert initially when calling the function from constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by comment the function call in constructor and inside of onappearing(), call the same function using the viewmodel class object(added in xaml.cs file not in viewmodel).

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
       {
        dbvm.UserList(); //dbvm is viewmodel class object
       }
```